# issue in creating Data frame by passing list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

after doing few data manipulation i got 2 list **avglist** and **sumlist** 
and now i passed this 2 list to my **result_df**

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({"File Name": filelist ,"Average":avglist,"Sum":sumlist})
print(result_df)
```

so below is my Output result, but problem here is

1) even my header Continental AG, datatype info also include..

i just my my values "874" and 584 in sum needed..

[image]

-i tried avglist.value(), but .value is not a list function

also tried few variation in .index but did not get expected result..

am i missing any steps here?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to extract `584` from string?

Comment: By the way, this is a very manual, unnecessarily long way of managing aggregation results. Instead of building the separate Series `avglist, sumlist` and then passing their `.values` into a DataFrame constructor, you should be able to run something like `df.groupby('File Name')['Continental AG: (Worldwide)'].agg(['mean', 'sum'])`

Comment: No avglist - its not a string... its a list and it has all int64 values

Comment: - @PeterLeimbigler yeah i understand.. but Avglist and Sumlist are the output result list,  after doing few data manipulation.. of multiple excel file

Comment: Gotcha. The problem seems to be that somewhere in your data manipulation, `avglist` and `sumlist` are accidentally converted from pandas Series to string representations. Maybe there's something like `avglist = print(avglist)` somewhere?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Nah, Nothing like that...i used append  : `avglist.append(avg1)`  with my each iteration the avglist gets updated...

Comment: but i somewhere feel that while reading the CSV file and converting it to dataframe even my headers column is included while taking avg & sum.. But i have set `header =2` while reading the file... and even in my `df.head()`  i see not issue... or issue in CSV file? i am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i performed few operation sometime like below...

```
while i < len(filepath):
  .....
  df['Date']=df['Time'].apply(lambda i:i.split('T')[0])
  .......
  .......
  sum1=sum_df.sum(axis=0)
  avg1=Avg_df.sum(axis=0)
  .......
  .......
  avglist.append(avg1)
  sumlist.append(sum1)
  .....
  i+=1
```

so i have changed my all operation to below..

```
 df['Date']=df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda i:i.split('T')[0])
 .........
 .........

 sum1=sum_df.iloc[:,0].sum()
 avg1=Avg_df.iloc[:,0].mean()
 .....
 .....
 avglist.append(avg1)
 sumlist.append(sum1)
```

instead of using column name, axis in my operation.

i updated to `dataframe.iloc` in all my operation and it started giving me correct result..

[image]

still not sure about precise reason , but this changes worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with how you're importing your files. If you take a `.sum()` of your dataframe, it will give you back the sum of the columns. I suspect you may be doing that since you are summing a dataframe. Then when you try to put the list in another dataframe its looking funky.

lets take the following two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 20, 30, 4, 0],
              'b':[1, 0, 3, 4, 0],
              'c':[1, 3, 7, 7, 5],
              'd':[1, 8, 3, 8, 5],
              'e':[1, 11, 3, 4, 0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 20, 100, 4, 0],
              'b':[1, 0, 39, 49, 10],
              'c':[1, 3, 97, 7, 95],
              'd':[441, 38, 23, 8, 115],
              'e':[1, 11, 13, 114, 0]})
```

looking at the sum of one of these dataframes:

```
df.sum()
a    55
b     8
c    23
d    25
e    19
dtype: int64
```

now if we were to take the sums of dataframes and put them in a list:

```
sums = [x.sum() for x in [df, df2]]
```

when we inspect this we get:

```
[a    55
 b     8
 c    23
 d    25
 e    19
 dtype: int64, a    125
 b     99
 c    203
 d    625
 e    139
 dtype: int64]
```

if you want the sum of the *whole dataframe* and not just by column, you can use `.sum().sum()` which will sum first by columns and then sum those columns

```
df.sum().sum()
130
```

so across dataframes it would be:

```
sums = [x.sum().sum() for x in [df, df2]]
```

doing the mean would depend on how your csvs are. if you were to do `.mean().mean()` that might be very different than what you're looking for. If its just 1 column every time it would be fine. but if it were more, it would be taking the mean of 5 columns, and then taking the mean of that (those 5 averages summed divided by 5).

lastly it looks like "Continental AG (Worldwide)" is the name of your column.

So in your for loop you should be doing:

```
sums = [df['Continental AG (Worldwide)'.sum() for df in list_dfs]
```